# RegEx, either 0, 1-9.1-9 or 10.0?

Tags: regex

I require a RegEx that validates the entered number to be either

- 0
- 1-9 **with** one decimal (*i.e. 5.5, but not 3.33 or 7*)
- 10.0

I was trying with the below RegEx, but I'm not succeeding..

```
/(0|[1-9]\.[1-9]|\10.0)/g
```

*fyi, in my system, a '0' means 'No grade entered', a 10.0 is the maximum and the minimum is a 1.0*

Comment: And what is wrong with your current pattern, which looks correct to me?

Comment: Why it needs to be regex? It would be a lot easier with any language

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen According to https://regex101.com/tests, this RegEx would also agree with 10.11, but somehow does not agree to 7.3. Which should be completely the opposite.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Because I'm using the platform called 'Mendix' and the only way to validate is RegEx..

Comment: Well the documentation says otherwise: https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/validation-rules you can have a `range` validation and apply other validations on it. Would not that be feasible?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hm, forgot about that one. Nevertheless, it accepts only a single ' >= ' or ' <= ', whilst I want 3 possibilities .. So RegEx is the way to go :)

Comment: Fair enough!! o/

Answer (score 3):

You're having problems probably because you're missing the start and end markers, e.g., `^` and `$`, hence, your solution is not bounded to the whole input.  Try:

```
/^(0|[1-9]\.[0-9]|10\.0)$/g
```

Comment: Thanks Cnst. I'm pretty new to RegEx and will try experiment with the start and end markers :)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer, you're welcome, glad it solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is more robust?

```
^0$|^[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}$|^10\.0$
```

Main things to worry about are the above ones will for example match `12.0`, because the `0` is not anchored. You also want to use `{1}` quantifiers in the decimal case, and include `[0-9]` after the decimal (so `7.0` is matched).

EDIT: Explanation of changes

- Adding `^` and `$` to each of the three options ensures that the match is the whole of the string. This means that for example, `^0$` matches `0` but does not match `0.0`, `01`, `6.0` or any other string where `0` is only part of the string.
- Changing `[1-9]` after the decimal point in the second option to `[0-9]` allows `7.0` to be matched, where it previously would not
- Adding the quantifiers `{1}` to the `[]` groups before and after the decimal point in the second option ensures that we match only a single digit. Previously, `[1-9]\.[0-9]` would match `12.1`, `5.33` and other strings where the match is only contained within the string. They are somewhat redundant with `^` and `$`, but with regexes I like failsafes...
- I also moved the escaping `\` in the third option to be before the decimal point, which seemed like a typo (we want to match a literal `.` not use `.` to mean any character)

Comment: Somehow, this does not match '7.3', according to Regex101.com.. :s

Comment: Odd, now it does :) Gotta have had a space added accidentally.. :)

Comment: FYI: this is not a good answer, because it does not at all attempt to explain why your solution works when the original one didn't.  (Additionally, the `{1}` quantifiers are basically a noop, so, it's not clear why they'd be needed at all.)

Answer (score 1):

My proposal:

```
(?<![0-9.])(0|(?:[1-9]\.[0-9])|(?:10\.0))(?![0-9.])
```

All of the following will match: 0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 9.0, 9.1, 9.9, 10.0, but all of the following will not: 0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 1.11, 1.20, 1.01, 10.05, 110.05. Does not require one-number per line, can extract numbers embedded in text.

Here is the example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0zK4Yt/2)

---

More detailed explanation:

```
(?<![0-9.])
```

is a look-behind that prevents us from ripping out pieces of number-literals in multi-line input, e.g. 10000010.0 should not be matched.

```
(0|(?:[1-9]\.[0-9])|(?:10\.0))
```

This is the part that matches your specification. The `?:` is needed only if you want to keep the matched groups "clean", in the sense that there will be no `group(2)` for the middle case

```
(?![0-9.])
```

This is another look ahead, again: important only for multi-line text.

If you drop look-behinds, look-aheads and "environmentally friendly match-groups", you end up with something like:

```
0|([1-9]\.[0-9])|(10\.0)
```

and if you are working with one-item-per-line input, you can add prefix `^` and suffix `$`, and go with that.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Just wondering.. It will only be applied to a single field, so multiline is not needed. Besides that, isn't your string unnecessary long compared to the others? Just wondering.

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer I added an explanation of the various "modules" and their purpose. If You drop all the look-aheads and look-behinds and match-groups, the regex becomes much shorter.